# Jenkins build cycling on maven release

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a Jenkins server running on a Linux box and some Java projects in BitBucket. I have a web hook in place to trigger a build on my Jenkins server when I commit changes to BitBucket. The triggering of the build is working fine and is doing a maven release prepare and perform. The problem I have is that when the version number in the pom is updated and pushed back to BitBucket another build is triggered and thus we end up in a loop.

I have experimented with using the SCM Skip plugin to try and break the loop. In the pom.xml release plugin section I set scmCommentPrefix to [ci skip]. This worked in so far as it stopped any further builds but it then would not do a build when I made further changes to the source code.

On investigation what is happening is that when the next build is triggered it is not only looking at the last commit message but all of the commit messages since the start of the previous successful build, which includes the commits from the maven release plugin that now contain [ci skip]. What I need it to do is only look at the very last commit message, if that contains [ci skip] then it should not do the build otherwise it should proceed.

Thanks for the help.
Andrew